# Imprimir una cadena de texto hasta ser interrumpida

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo hago para que el programa no me imprima la palabra `"salir"` junto con las otras frases ingresadas y solo imprima `frases ingresadas(-"salir") + "hasta pronto!"`?

Mi código:

```js
    do{
      var str = prompt("Ingrese una frase: ");
      console.log(str);
    }while(str != "salir"){
      console.log("Hasta pronto!");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La lógica original está bastante cerca, he hecho un par de cambios:

- Declaro la variable antes del `do`/`while`, no tiene mayor efecto, pero es más ordenado, ya que se utiliza como condición del `while`, no le veo sentido a declararla cada iteración.
- He movido el mensaje de hasta pronto a un `if/then/else`, que dependiendo del mensaje ingresado imprime uno u otro.

```js
var str
do{
  str = prompt("Ingrese una frase: ");
  if (str == "salir") {
    console.log("Hasta pronto!");
  } else {
    console.log(str);
  }
}while(str != "salir")
```

Answer (score 4):

Dos opciones:

1. O pones `console.log(str);` encima del `prompt()` (en cuyo caso tendrás que declarar `str` fuera del while y lo inicializas a una cadena vacía (así no te imprime nada).
2. Pones el `console.log(str);` dentro de un `if` que compruebe si `str !== 'salir'`.

### Opción 1

```js
var str = '';

do {
  console.log(str);
  var str = prompt("Ingrese una frase: ");
} while(str != "salir");

console.log("Hasta pronto!");
```

### Opción 2

```js
do {
  var str = prompt("Ingrese una frase: ");
  
  if (str !== "salir") {
      console.log(str);
  }
} while(str != "salir");

console.log("Hasta pronto!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta con pedir la cadena y comprobar si es la cadena "salir" para mostrar el mensaje de despedida y en caso contrario volver a llamar a la misma funcion indefinidamente.

Te pongo un ejemplo sencillo:

```js
pedirStrings()

function pedirStrings(){
  var str = prompt("Ingrese una frase: ");
  if(str == "salir"){
    console.log('Hasta pronto!');
  }
  else{
    console.log(str);
    pedirStrings();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Pruébalo desde mi respuesta en el botón ejecutar y verás que funciona, escribe un par de cadenas y luego salir y la de salir no sale en la consola. @YazinCastañoMoreno

Comment: Tal vez tengas algún otro console.log

Comment: Esto hace una llamada recursiva que, a mi parecer, es innecesaria.

Comment: Se puede hacer con un bucle sin embargo a mi me resulta más cómodo trabajar con esta metodología y es otra alternativa a las otras respuestas que hay no quiere decir que sea mejor o peor @jachguate

Comment: ojala el usuario no ingrese mil veces y genere un stackoverflow por una recursion totalmente innecesario (funciona, si, es una buena solucion, tengo mis serias duda)

Comment: Si no me equivoco el prompt detiene la ejecución al igual que la recarga de la página detiene los scripts que no han terminado, de todas formas tiene pinta de ser un ejercicio de aprendizaje y esta respuesta sería una buena opción si por ejemplo se quiere lanzar el proceso al pulsar un botón por ejemplo. Esta bien tener diferentes alternativas a una solución

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción podría ser utilizando `while(true)`, el cual se ejecutará hasta que sea llamando `break`.

#### Ejemplo

```js
while (true) {
  let str = prompt("Ingrese una frase: ");
  if (str == "salir") break;
  console.log(str);
}
console.log("Hasta pronto!");
```